# python: Pandas groupby & apply optimization

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

i have the following line of code:

`df.groupby([col1]).apply( lambda x: x.loc[x[col2] == val, col3].sum() / x.loc[x[col2] == val_0, col3].sum());`

My `df` is on the large side (~300000 rows) and the *groupby* produces ~2300 groups.
As a result, execution time is rather big...

Any ideas on how to optimize it?

Thank you in advanced!

Python version: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can filter first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'col2':[2,4,6,3,2,4,1,2],
                    'col3':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]})
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     2     1
1    a     4     2
2    a     6     1
3    a     3     2
4    b     2     1
5    b     4     2
6    b     1     1
7    b     2     2

val = 4
val_0 = 2

a = df[df['col2'] == val]
b = df[df['col2'] == val_0]

c = a.groupby('col1')['col3'].sum() / b.groupby('col1')['col3'].sum()
print (c)
col1
a    2.000000
b    0.666667
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```